# AlivePdf Unicode character

Tags: actionscript-3, alivepdf

It's possible using alivepdf to write a Unicode pdf?

I see a Unicode.as class, but when I try, the pdf created cannot be opened by adobe reader.

Could you please suggest me some code snippet to create a unicode string?

[EDIT]

I have made some investigations. I think the problem is on putcidfont0 method on UnicodePDF.as class.

The problem is that I think the font metrics are not parsed well and many characters are displayed with the default font width.

I cannot say how to fix this...

Comment: I know it's very late, but did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some characters, as greek accented, some polish and many other characters are not available trough cid fonts, so the only way is to embed font in pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Try delcaring a new `UnicodePDF()` or setting the `isUnicode` bit to true ([see documentation](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/alivepdf-asdoc/org/alivepdf/pdf/UnicodePDF.html))

I dealt with this a month or two ago. My issue was that certain characters I would pass to AlivePDF would result in a broken PDF.

In my case I still had issues and my research turned up no promising results, although [someone else had a strikingly similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/issues/detail?id=175) that may be worth reading in your case.

The AlivePDF library hasn't been updated in a few years, and with my experience it seems like it doesn't play entirely well with unicode / other languages, although I have used it for English content without issue.

Since my target was desktop Flash and I was generating the PDF content from an external XML file, I eventually just wrote a helper utility app using C# and [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/), which may or may not be an option in your case.

Comment: I should read some json. Can I format the json and then output a well formatted pdf? SO for example, can I format some chinese text and pass it to alivepdf?

Answer (score 0):

There was a big discussion [here](https://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/issues/detail?id=175)

Also I noticed that online PDF to Doc converters read UnicodePDF() files well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've already read that discussion. My problem is that my unicode pdf cannot be open by adobe reader, foxit reader instead can read.I'm trying to modify the library, but after a look to pdf reference, it seems too hard to get a decent result with unicode, so I was searching for a help from other developer...

Comment: The strange thing is that I can output an inline pdf with unicode characters well formatted, except some character that add an extra space, like c cedilla. Cannot say if it's a map problem or other issue